# What event fires when elements are added or removed in the document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dom, tiddlywiki

I am making a sort of tabbed interface for a Tiddlywiki, and I am wondering how to get this code to fire every time a tiddler is opened or closed. Tiddlywiki is an HTML notebook type of thing that runs in the browser, and a tiddler is a div in `#tiddlerDisplay`. There can be, and usually are, more than one in it at a time.

The divs I want to list are contained in `#tiddlerDisplay`, and the list itself is `jQuery("#mainMenu > #singleTiddlerList")`.

```
config.macros.singleTiddler.update = function(){
    jQuery("#mainMenu > #singleTiddlerList").empty();
    jQuery("#tiddlerDisplay > div").each(function(i,e){
        jQuery("#mainMenu > #singleTiddlerList").append(jQuery(
            createTiddlyButton(document.createElement("li"),jQuery(e).attr("tiddler"),"",config.macros.singleTiddler.clickHandler)
        ).parent());
    });
};
```

**Update:** I can't just add a custom event, unless I can do it from outside the current code (such as something that fires on document load).

Comment: how about creating custom events with bind() that do the removal/appending and trigger them so that you can have back an event response?

Comment: I don't have control of the code that does the opening and closing and I don't want to override it either. Can this be done from the plugin?

Comment: I'll make this an answer, see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is `jQuery("#tiddlerDisplay").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", config.macros.singleTiddler.update);`, however i think this only works in Chrome (maybe Opera or Safari, not sure), and also appears to be deprecated. Firefox has a duo of events to accomplish the same thing, but i think these are also deprecated.

Another way I found after reading [this article](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2009-Using-Self-Executing-Function-Arguments-To-Override-Core-jQuery-Methods.htm) and exploring the TiddlyWiki source code is this:

```
(function( $, oldRem ){
    Story.prototype.displayTiddler = function(){
        var resp = oldRem.apply( this, arguments );
        $("#tiddlerDisplay").trigger("displayTiddler");
        return(resp);
    };
})( jQuery, Story.prototype.displayTiddler );
(function( $, oldRem ){
    Story.prototype.closeTiddler = function(){
        var resp = oldRem.apply( this, arguments );
        $("#tiddlerDisplay").trigger("closeTiddler");
        return(resp);
    };
})( jQuery, Story.prototype.closeTiddler );
jQuery("#tiddlerDisplay").bind("displayTiddler", config.macros.singleTiddler.update);
jQuery("#tiddlerDisplay").bind("closeTiddler", config.macros.singleTiddler.update);
```

Notice that the event fires *after* the tiddler opens or closes. Also, as the article states, jQuery can be bugged in the same way, but I don't know about the native DOM methods, and I kind of doubt it. There's supposed to be an event for it, but regardless, everyone should totally drop them and use jQuery!

Comment: My brain is racing with all the posibilities this opens up! A year ago I was wishing for exactly this. It's amazing how sometimes when you can't figure something out, and you come back to it later, it just kind of falls into place.

Comment: I don't know if this is called an override or not, but this works great for me. I just have to beware of another plugin overriding it. I call this method bugging.

Answer (score 0):

First create two custom events for your append/clearing of divs. Have them bind in the document you use the code posted above.

```
jQuery(document).bind('div-removed',function(e){ 
  // code stuff to do for removal 
  jQuery("#mainMenu > #singleTiddlerList").empty(); // required
  // other stuff here
});
jQuery(document).bind('div-appended',function(e){ 
 // code stuff to do on append 
        jQuery("#tiddlerDisplay > div").each(function(i,e){
            jQuery("#mainMenu > #singleTiddlerList").append(jQuery(
                createTiddlyButton(document.createElement("li"),jQuery(e).attr("tiddler"),"",config.macros.singleTiddler.clickHandler)
            ).parent());
        }); // required
  //other stuff here
});
```

Then in your code change slightly the execution:

```
config.macros.singleTiddler.update = function(){
  $(document).trigger("div-removed");
  $(document).trigger("div-appended");  
};
```

It's definitely not the only way (I think now it can also be done with `.promise()` but it's a start. **update** updated to check if this works.

Comment: Will the first trigger only fire when all the divs are removed or whenever a div is removed?

Comment: Wait, I think there is a misunderstanding here. The tiddlers are in `#tiddlerDisplay` and the list is in `#singleTiddlerList`. I've updated my question to reflect this. The code I don't want to edit is the code that adds and removes divs from `#tiddlerDisplay`.

Comment: Hmm maybe [this](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) will help you then. Maybe you need delegation.

Comment: What event do I assign? Does JavaScript have a function hook feature that can fire an event when a function is called?

Comment: Can you see if the new code works? Actually you break the inner code to two events, that are fired and execute the excess code inside.

Comment: It says removed is not defined, but that may be an error on my part. However, I don't quite think you understand what I'm trying to do. All I want to do is catch the event that fires (if one does) when a div is added to or removed from the div with ID `#singleTiddlerList`.